# PHP mime_content_type not returning anything

Tags: php, image-uploading, mime-types

I've tried this a couple of times now and this is the closest I think I am to getting it work properly. I have similar code elsewhere and it works properly but when I execute this one the mime_content_type doesn't return anything.  I've tried to get it to work in a lot of different ways let me know if you see something that I'm overlooking.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; ++ $i) {

                $mime = false;

                if (preg_match ( '/(jpeg|png|gif|jpg|jpe)/i', $_FILES ['listing'] ['type'] ['images'] [$i] )) {

                    $new_image = new image_handler ( $_FILES ['listing'] ['tmp_name'] ['images'] [$i] );

                    $m = mime_content_type ( $new_image );

                    if ($m == 'image/png' || $m == 'image/jpeg' || $m == 'image/gif') {
                        $mime = true;
                    }

                    if ($mime) {
                        $new_images [$i] ['name'] = date ( 'ymdgis' ) . $_FILES ['listing'] ['name'] ['images'] [$i];
                        $new_images [$i] ['default'] = ($_POST ['listing'] ['default_image'] == $i) ? true : false;

                        $new_image->save ( IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, REAL_PATH . 'uploads/listings/' . $new_images [$i] ['name'] );
                        $new_image->save ( THUMB_SIZE, THUMB_SIZE, REAL_PATH . 'uploads/listings/thumbnails/' . $new_images [$i] ['name'] );
                    }
                } elseif ((! preg_match ( '/(jpeg|png|gif|jpg|jpe)/i', $_FILES ['listing'] ['type'] ['images'] [$i] )) && ($_FILES ['listing'] ['name'] ['images'] [$i] != '')) {
                    $pass_message .= '<p>The File ' . $_FILES ['listing'] ['name'] ['images'] [$i] . ' was not uploaded due to its filetype.</p>';
                }
                if (! $mime && ($_FILES ['listing'] ['name'] ['images'] [$i] != '')) {
                    $pass_message .= '<p>The File ' . /*$_FILES ['uploads'] ['name'] ['image']*/ $m . ' was not uploaded due to its mime type.</p>';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, [mime_content_type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) takes the filename as an input parameter.

In your example, you're instantiating a new image_handler() object that you pass onto the mime_content_type() function.

I believe you should have a method in your class to get the file path.

Something like this:

```
$new_image = new image_handler ( $_FILES ['listing'] ['tmp_name'] ['images'] [$i] );
$filename = $new_image->get_filename_method();

$m = mime_content_type ( $filename );
```